# Rails create a helper to add text

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `fee` column in my model and it is an integer type, so I try to create a tiny helper to add a dollar sign neatly in front. Which means, instead of writing:

```
span = "$#{@object.fee}"
```

I can write something like

```
span = @object.fee.dollar
```

So I created the tiny helper.

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def self.dollar
        "$#{self.try(:to_s)}"
    end
end
```

I am not sure where to put it, so basically it's now showing

> undefined method `dollar' for 180:Fixnum

Comment: `dollar` isn't magically put into other classes, you'd call `<%= dollar @object.fee %>`. And the method would take a parameter. Not sure what you think helpers are/do.

Comment: As an aside, try to avoid using reserved words like "span" as a variable name. It's a reserved html word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**number_to_currency()**

Rails 4.2 has this ActionView::Helper

```
number_to_currency(1234567890.506)
```

**Helper**

If you want to implement this as a helper, this works

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def dollar(amount)
       amount = number_to_currency(amount)
    end
end
```

**Invoke**

```
<%= dollar(your_var_here) %>
```

**Rails spec for number_to_currency()**

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency

---

*Note: Other versions of Rails may have this function, you'd have to check your version.*

Answer (score 0):

Your helpers are included in the view context, so you need two changes:

1. `def dollar` - because it's included in the renderer, you don't need `self`
2. Call it as `dollar(@object.fee)` - it's not included on the object, but in your view. If you want to call it as `@object.dollar`, declare the method in whatever class `@object` is.

Additionally, the [number_to_currency](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency) helper already exists and is quite robust. Perhaps you want to use that.

Answer (score 0):

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def dollar(amount)
        "$#{amount}"
    end
end
```

and then:

`span = dollar @object.fee`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're in a helper, so you can't refer to `self`.

You can do it in your Model, or in the helper do : 
`def print_dollar(your_value)`

Or, you can also use : `number_to_currency(dollar, :unit => "$")`, which will render it the way you want.

Hope it help

Comment: Definitely doesn't belong in the model. A decorator, sure.